# Can not resolve symbol "FirebaseMessagingService"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm tring to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging in android app but facing problem to extend `FirebaseMessagingService` in our class.

It displaying **Can not resolve symbol "FirebaseMessagingService"**

app.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
```

and also add google-service.json file

Comment: Please always use a single version of all Firebase dependencies. Mixing versions is a recipe for headaches.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for ur valuable comment

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you also need to add

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
```

Comment: check latest dependency here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?authuser=0#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk

Answer (score 5):

You have **to add another dependency**:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

Check the [official doc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Answer (score 2):

```
dependencies {    
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies it will solve your problem

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
 }
```